# Change code in non-virtual method with Fody

Tags: .net, fody

Is it possible to change code in a non-virtual method using Fody or some other framework? I'm not looking to mock it but rather change the code in the generated assembly at compile-time.

Ex. I would like to change:

```
private int SomeInt() { return 1; }
```

to

```
private int SomeInt() { return 42; }
```

in an assembly without mocking it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do that with Fody. But writing a Fody plugin is non trivial.

Comment: @KirkWoll Is Fody ModuleWeaver the simplest path? Got a link that I can look at? TIA I've only used Fody ModuleInitializer before.

Comment: Creating a module weaver is the only way to write a fody plugin. After looking at the [sample](https://github.com/Fody/BasicFodyAddin), your best bet is to look at the [suite of existing](https://github.com/Fody/FodyAddinSamples) plugins.